# Ribbon labelControl GetSuperTip doesn't work

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, vsto, ribbon

According to the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd909137%28v=office.12%29.aspx), a `labelControl` supports the `getSupertip` property for setting a tooltip on the ribbon control.

For some reason though, the tooltip isn't working. An identical implementation works on other controls (like `button`), but not `labelControl`. Furthermore, other callbacks such as `getLabel` work for the label, just not `getSupertip`.

Any idea what's wrong?

**Ribbon XML**

```xml
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="custom" label="Custom AddIn">
        <group id="ConfigGroup" label="Configuration">
          <labelControl id="lb1" getLabel="GetLabel" getSupertip="GetSupertip" />
          <button id="bt1" label="Set Server URL" getSupertip="GetSupertip" />
          ...
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**Ribbon Code**

```cs
public class CustomRibbon : ExcelRibbon, IExcelAddIn
{
    public string GetSupertip(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        switch (control.Id)
        {
            case "lb1":
                return "The current server address is: " + API.serverURL;
            case "bt1":
                return "Click to change the server URL. (Currently: " + 
                       API.serverURL + ")";
        }
    }
```

**Image of `getLabel` working for `labelControl` and `getSupertip` working on `button` only.**
[image: labelControl label working and tooltip working on button]

Comment: For future viewers with the same problem, consider that: "The `getSupertip` and `supertip` attributes are mutually exclusive. If neither attribute is specified, no `supertip` for this control should be shown." (from the documentation). This, however, is not the issue in this case.

Comment: See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx#OfficeCustomizingRibbonUIforDevelopers2_Detailed - a document that discusses all the controls and their shared properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is a Microsoft bug. Either the documentation lists **`getSupertip`** as a property by mistake, or the property is there but the implementation makes no use of it. Either way, there's no way to get a Supertip or other tooltip text on a `labelControl`.

This is the response I've received on the MSDN forums: [ribbon-labelcontrol-getsupertip-doesnt-work](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd4cb85f-03cd-4ea8-8238-041b721d236a/ribbon-labelcontrol-getsupertip-doesnt-work)